# Access the registry data to set the linker and include paths

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, include

I'm writing a C++ program in VS2102 using some given libraries and header files from some other Software which offers those files as an API (located in the "software installation folder" + \include\lib\x86 or \include\lib\x64).

Now I want to ensure that my program works even if the installation path differs, so I need to extract the installation path from the registry and dynamically change the include path linker settings. Is this possible?

*Edit* I'm compiling my program to a dll for later use in a C# Project. Is it possible to set the installation path (and therefore the linker and include project settings) to a global variable, compile the program to a dll (with an existing and working setup) and later reset this variable by an external program before the first loading of the dll via `dllimport`?

Comment: Is there an environment variable of some sort for the software being installed?

Comment: Are you asking for VS2012 installation path, or installation path for "some other Software"? If the the former, then just use the `VS120COMNTOOLS` environment variable. To see all such variables, issue command `set vs` in the command interpreter.

Comment: sadly, I need a linker to some other installed software whitch is offering those libs / header files as an API. I have no environment variable with the installation path, but I could extract that (at runtime) using the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSBuild offers a syntax to read values (and initialise build properties) out of the registry [linked here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx) and [direct link here for VS2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3).

> You can read system registry values by using the following syntax, where **Hive** is the registry hive (for example, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`), **Key** is the key name, **SubKey** is the subkey name, and **Value** is the value of the subkey.
>
> ```
> $(registry:Hive\MyKey\MySubKey@Value)
> ```
>
> To get the default subkey value, omit the **Value**.
>
> ```
> $(registry:Hive\MyKey\MySubKey)
> ```
>
> This registry value can be used to initialize a build property. For example, to create a build property that represents the Visual Studio web browser home page, use this code:
>
> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
>   <VisualStudioWebBrowserHomePage>
>      $(registry:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\WebBrowser@HomePage)
>   </VisualStudioWebBrowserHomePage>
> <PropertyGroup>
> ```

Once read, you can use the build property in the project's additional include and library paths.

For example it could look like;

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ThirdPartySoftware_1>
    $(registry:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ThirdPartySW_1\@InstalledLocation
  </ThirdPartySoftware_1>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And be added to the project files, or included via a .props file.

*From your edit...* the build requirements are not the same as the runtime requirements. The runtime loading issue is solved by making sure the correct folder is in the path; or more likely for your scenario, distribute the correct dll for the target platform.

---

As an alternative, you can also take this on as an environment setup task (or as a post install task related to the third party software).

> located in the software installation folder + `\include\lib\x86` or `\include\lib\x64`

Set the installation path of the third party software to "software installation folder" as required. For example (in the system environment variables);

```
ThirdPartySoftware_1 = "software installation folder";
```

Once done, this can be used in the IDE to add to the include path;

```
$(ThirdPartySoftware_1)\include
```

And library path;

```
$(ThirdPartySoftware_1)\include\lib\$(Platform)
```

*The above assumes* that the `$(Platform)` variable is either `x86` or `x64`. Sometimes the wizards generate a `Win32` platform for the `x86`.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the fast help!